# Install visual studio without previous update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Yesterday I had a computercrash and now I need to reïnstall all of my programs. These programs also include Visual Studio 2012.

I knew there were a lot of updates (3, i guess) and I'm wondering what problems is possibly can have when I first install update 3, without installing update 1 or 2.

Should there be any bugs or regressions i should take account of? Update 3 is now installing and it's doing fine (no errors so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012.3 includes versions 1 & 2 as well, otherwise the installer would tell you to instal first the previous versions.

There is no problem for you, it is like Windows Service Packs, so you won't have bugs or regressions.

**EDIT:**

[Official source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600):

> Visual Studio 2012 updates are cumulative releases that include the
>   new features and fixes that were delivered in previous releases.